# Convert mousemove coordinate of an placeholder on pdf and convert to pdf coordinnates with pdfjs fpdi js

Tags: javascript, canvas, pdf.js

I want to retrieve the exact coordinates of a placeholder on a pdf to add a signature.

My problem, I don't know how to convert mousemove event coordinates in js to pdf coordinates.
I am using this library https://codepen.io/ValerioEmanuele/pen/pGRZqe but the coordinates I got from it are not the same as the pdf coordinates.
So I want help to achieve my goal of placing a placeholder and getting its coordinates corresponding to the pdf.

```
// y=> position Y of element on mousemove
// x=> position X of element on mousemove 
var pdfY = y * maxPDFLy / maxHTMLy;
var posizioneY = maxPDFy - offsetY - pdfY;
var posizioneX = (x * maxPDFx / maxHTMLx) - paramContainerWidth;
```